# Remove optional tag for parameters user script processing toolbox QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, toolbox

I have sucessfully written my first QGIS processing toolbox.
But have this bizzare optional tag on my parameters and i would like to remove these tags.

[image: Parameters tagged optionnel]

```
##Fichier_csv=file
##Dossier_de_sortie=folder
##nomodeler

import sys
import re 
import os
import csv
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from qgis.core import *
import processing

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
final_list = []
f_csv = Fichier_csv
op = Dossier_de_sortie
with open(f_csv, "rU") as s:  
    reader_tables = csv.DictReader(s,delimiter=';')
    liste_tables = list(reader_tables)
    l_tables = [i['table'] for i in liste_tables]
    l_tables = set(l_tables)
    for table in l_tables:
        l1 = [line for line in liste_tables if line['table'] == table] 
        geometry = l1[1]['geometry']
        layer_mem = QgsVectorLayer(geometry+"?crs=epsg:2154",table,"memory")
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer_mem,os.path.join(op,table),"utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile",False)
        layer_path = os.path.join(op,table)
        shp = QgsVectorLayer(layer_path,table,'ogr')
        pr = shp.dataProvider()
        shp.startEditing()
        for field in l1:
            if field['type'] != 'Double':
                pr.addAttributes([QgsField(field['field'],getattr(QVariant,field['type']),field['typeName'],int(field['len']))])
            else:
                pr.addAttributes([QgsField(field['field'],getattr(QVariant,field['type']),field['typeName'],int(field['len']),int(field['precision']))])
        shp.updateFields()
        shp.commitChanges()
        del layer_mem,shp,pr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by slightly editing the source code for a processing parameter file and changing the optional setting. In your QGIS installation directory, go to:

```
../apps/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/
```

And open the `parameters.py`. Search for the following line:

```
class ParameterFile(Parameter)
```

In its `__init__()` method, change the following:

```
optional=True
```

[image: Change from True]

to

```
optional=False
```

[image: To False]

*Note that depending on permissions, you may need to save the file somewhere else, move/delete the original then move the newly saved on in its place.*

---

Restart QGIS and hopefully those tags should no longer appear when you run the script. **Keep in mind that these parameters must now be filled as they are no longer optional.**

[image: Result]